# git merge conflicts even with git reset --hard

Tags: git, repository, git-merge, git-pull, git-reset

I am working on a branch on a repository. I commit and push changes every day to origin from one computer. Then on another computer the next day I do `git pull` and expect the changes pushed from the day before to be updated in my working directory.

I keep receiving :

```
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in src/main.c
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

Ok, so I then do a `git reset --hard HEAD` , which should undo any local and uncommited changes that I have, and then do `git pull` again. However, the conflict error remains.

This is not the behavior I expect. Previously for me, `git reset --hard HEAD` followed by `git pull` would solve this. But not anymore:)

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `git merge --abort`?

Comment: @tkausl I did, and still the same when I try to pull afterwards

Comment: Ah I misunderstood, you're just trying to pull again after resetting. Seems like you can't. How about resolving those conflicts?

Comment: @tkausl I abslolutely don't want to be manually merging conflicts, when it should just do it automatically. With one file, ok, but with multiple files, it's a pain. I simply want my working directory in the state it was from the day before

Comment: @tkausl The way i'm solving it now is by deleteing my local repository creating a new one, checking out my branch from scratch again and it is in the state I want it to be. There must be an easier way.

Comment: If you don't care about local commits just reset to the origin branch.

Comment: What do you see when you open the file with conflicts (src/main.c)? Any hints of where the conflicts might come from? There should be conflict markers which might give you an idea of what is going on.

Comment: @tkausl Ok in fact git reset origin/<my-branch> has solved it for me. Thanks. I still don't know why git reset --hard HEAD with git pull doesn't work in my case for discarding local changes and updating to HEAD

Answer (score 0):

`git reset --hard HEAD` and `git merge --abort` do the same thing:

- abort the ongoing merge; and
- copy all of the committed files from `HEAD` (the current commit) to both Git's index and your working tree.

The merge conflict occurs because the changes on your *current branch* collide with the changes on the incoming commits from your `git pull`.  That is, your `git pull` is running:

1. `git fetch`; then
2. `git merge arguments` (where the *arguments* are somewhat complicated for historical reasons)

The second step, the `git merge`, is in effect `git merge HEAD@{upstream}`, and is finding some merge work to do:

```
          I--J   <-- your-branch (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   [merge base]
         \
          K--L   <-- origin/your-branch
```

For Git to merge changes since the common starting point—here, commit `H`—as made by you on commits `I` and `J` with changes made by someone else on commits `K` and `L`, Git must *compare* (as in `git diff`) the snapshot *in* that common starting point commit against the snapshots in the two branch-tip commits:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-H> <hash-of-J>   # what we changed
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-H> <hash-of-L>   # what they changed
```

Git's `git merge` then attempts to *combine* these two sets of changes.  When it does so, it encounters a set of changes it *cannot combine:*

> ```
> CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in src/main.c
> Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
> ```

That is, from `H` to `J`, *you* changed something in `src/main.c`, and from `H` to `L`, *they* changed something in `src/main.c` as well, and *those two changes disagree with each other*.

You get a merge conflict because Git can't combine these changes on its own.  Running `git merge --abort`, or `git reset --hard HEAD`, just gets you back to the pre-`git merge` state; running `git pull` again causes `git merge` to run the same two `git diff`s, combine them the same way, hit the same problem, and stop with the same error.

> ... `git reset origin/<my-branch>` has solved it for me

What this did was to *throw away your work*.  That is, given the above diagram, the `git reset` did this:

```
          I--J   ???
         /
...--G--H   <-- your-branch (HEAD)
         \
          K--L   <-- origin/your-branch
```

(although `git reset --mixed` followed by `git merge` would produce an error, so my guess is that you added in a `--hard` somewhere).

After such a `git reset`, the merge *will work*, but that's because *you discarded all your own work*.  If that's what you wanted, you're all set.